# Difference between in size and the size and of the size

Tags: meaning

> The shirts are the size XXL
>
> The shirts are of the  size  XXL
>
> The shirts are in size XXL.

Is there any difference between three sentences? If there are differences I couldn’t understand what are those?

Comment: The first two aren't right. The third one is alright, but a more common alternative would be 'The shirts are size XXL' although I am struggling to think of the difference between those.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @JacobLee-Hart that the only correct sentences are:

(1) The shirts are size XXL.

(2) The shirts are in size XXL.

The difference between (1) and (2) is that (1) specifies the size of certain shirts while (2) indicates the size in which they are available.

Comment: You might also hear “The shirts are *sized* XXL.”